# Automapper: i need to call "CreateMap" for every single copy of Entity - DTO?

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-6

I'm using Automapper (6.2.1) for convert a hierarchy of Entity objects:

```
class Entity1 {}
class Entity2 : Entity1 {}
class Entity3 : Entity1 {}
```

To a corresponding hierarchy of DTO objects:

```
class EntityDTO1 {}
class EntityDTO2 : EntityDTO1 {}
class EntityDTO3 : EntityDTO1 {}
```

I have mapped all the convertions like this:

```
 CreateMap<Entity1, EntityDTO1>();
 CreateMap<Entity2, EntityDTO2>();
 CreateMap<Entity3, EntityDTO3>();
```

Every time I create one Entity and one DTO i will need to add a new `CreateMap` call to my configuration file.

There isn't a more compact method for do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you use name conventions you can do something like this:

```
 AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(map =>
            {
                var asmEntities = Assembly.Load("DomainLibrary");
                var asmDtos = Assembly.Load("ViewModelsLibrary");

                foreach (Type entity in asmEntities.GetTypes())
                {
                    var vm = asmDtos.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == $"{entity.Name}Vm");
                    if (vm != null)
                    {
                        map.CreateMap(entity, vm).ReverseMap();
                    }
                }
}

  //  exemple names: 

Entity = Product
ViewModel = ProductVm
```

and this is a method which I use to get the entity dynamic:

```
 public static object GetEntity(object model)
        {
            var map = AutoMapper.Mapper
                .Configuration
                .GetAllTypeMaps()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.SourceType == model.GetType());

            if (map == null) return null;

            return AutoMapper.Mapper
                .Map(model, model.GetType(), map.DestinationType);

        }
```